# PowerShell: get data between two strings

Tags: powershell

I've got next data into variable $out (type is Object[]):

```
Success...
Go!
0:#217> trace && .quit
   0x000 Subline         : _OK
   0x008 Timed      : NO
   0x016 Check     : _OK
   0x022 Post       : 
   0x030 Offset         : None
   0x038 Hint     : False
   0x050 NextHint    : False
quit:
```

I need extract text between string **0:#217> trace && .quit** and **quit:**
I wrote:

```
[Regex]::Match($out, "(?<=.quit').+?(?=quit:)").Value
```

But this extracts required data into a line (type String), not a column (Object[]). How to fix this?

**P.S.**
I solved the problem by myself as follows

```
([Regex]'(?is)(?:(?<=\.quit).+(?=quit:))').Match(($out -join "`n")).Value
```

But maybe there is more perfect way to do this?

Comment: When I run your regex on a `String[]` which came from `Get-Content`, I get no results. Using @jisaak's answer on a `String[]`, I do get results - and you don't. How did you create `$out`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved

```
([Regex]'\s+0x([^q]+)').Match(($out -join "`n")).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `-split` function to create a `String[]` of your result:

```
$result = ([regex]::Match($a, '\.quit(.*)quit:').Groups[1].value) -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: Try to split using `n

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: this will work if `$out` is a `String[]`, e.g. from `$out = Get-Content results.txt`, from your other comments, you might have something different].

As a general approach, have a true/false flag which chooses whether lines are allowed through or not, and when you see the first line then set the flag, and when you see the last line you want, change the flag.

```
$middle = foreach ($line in $out) {
    if ($line -match '^quit') { $allow = $false }
    if ($allow) { write-output $line }
    if ($line -match '0:#217>') { $allow = $true }
}
```

The ordering of the tests determines whether the start or end lines show up in the results or not.

This can be shortened on the console for typing, into something like:

```
#   loop  # end line clears flag       # print?     # start line sets flag
$out |% { if($_ -match '^quit'){$f=0}; if ($f){$_}; if ($_ -match '0:#217>'){$f=1} }
```

Comment: Yeah, yeah... getting required data in cycle is very bad idea!

Comment: ... why is it a "very bad idea"?

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but it makes some assumptions:

```
$out -match '^ '
```

1. $out is always a String[]. Force it with `@($out)` if it might be a single string.
2. You are using PowerShell v4 or v5, so `-operator` will act as a filter on an array.
3. Your example data is accurate, and all the lines you want start with a space, and all the other lines do not.

Answer (score 0):

The following is for very simple searches, get the string data between a starting string and ending string.

**Upsides**
Very simplistic

**Downsides**
Does poorly for data with multiple matches etc

**Code**

```
Function Get-StringBetweenStartEnd {
    Param($Text,$Start,$End)
    $Regex = [Regex]::new("(?<="+$Start+")(.*)(?="+$End+")")           
    $Match = $Regex.Match($String)           
    if($Match.Success) { Return $Match.Value}else{Return ""}
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
$String = "Test: disconnected: 10.10.10.1::59270 (VNC Viewer closed)"           
$Result = Get-StringBetweenStartEnd -Text $String -Start "nected:" -End "::"
$Result.Trim()
```

*Output:*

10.10.10.1